# Chrome 9.0 on Mac prompts for form twice

Tags: forms, google-chrome, multipartform-data

I'm using Google Chrome 9.0 on a Mac, and for some reason whenever I upload a file to a site using the form enctype Chrome prompts me for the file twice. I click on the button, then select a file and click "Choose," and then the file dialog pops up again. The file I select in the second dialog is the one that is eventually uploaded to the site. I do not have the same problem in Firefox or Safari. I set up a reduced test case here:

http://rssafter5.appspot.com/index2.html

Do you know what the problem is?

```
<div id="container" style="margin-top:50px;"> 

    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="opml" method="post" action="/opml/myfeeds_after5.opml"> 

        <input type="file" style="width: 380px;" name="opml_file"> 
        <input type="submit" id="file_sub_button" value="Submit OPML File"> 
    </form> 

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed in the latest Chrome build - 9.0.597.10 - http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=65532

Update and it will probably be fixed